# Is it a jQuery bug or what?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am investigating what can be sent and what cannot be sent through jquery ajax, because it gives me erroneous results. At first I thought it's something to do with path characters. But I found out it really isn't.

So i wrote a web service which records what has been sent and a jQuery AJAX code which sends 38 symbols. But everytime, my web service records different symbols and in different order. My code is as follows.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="original"></div>
    <div id="returnedsybmols"></div>
    <div id="returnedunicode"></div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var symbols = "! \" # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ ! ￠ ￡ ? \\ | §";
            //var unicode ="サイトは有効なHTMLマークアップを使っていません。テキストを貼り付けてください。";

            var eachsymbol = symbols.split(' ');
            //alert(eachsymbol.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < eachsymbol.length; i++) {

            }


            eachsymbol.forEach(function (t) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "jsonstring.asmx/symbols",
                    data: "{'send':'" + t + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        var returnedText = msg.d;
                        $("#returnedsysmbols").append($("<p>").text(returnedText) );
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace ASP_NET
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for jsonstring
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class jsonstring : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string symbols(string send)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"E:\My Documents\programming\exercise\ASP_NET\ASP_NET\writeout\symbols4.txt"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(send);
            }

            return send;
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string unicode(string send)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\My Documents\programming\exercise\ASP_NET\ASP_NET\writeout\unicode.txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(send + " ");
            }

            return send;
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently \, ', " cannot be passed through jQuery. I tried using the escape function but it will encode all my unicode characters. Any solution for that?
And can you explain why my web server records different number and different set of character each time?

run case1
" ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = # ! % & ? >  [ ` ^ { ! ~ ? | ￡ §

run case 2
$ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < # " % ! & = > [ ] _ ` } | { ? ! ~ ￠ ￡ §

run case 3
! $ & % ( ) * - + . , / < > ? ^ _  } ~ ! ￠ ? ￡ § |

run case 4
$ ( ) * + , - . / : ; & " # < ? ! > = _ [  ` | { } ~ ￡ | ! ? ￠

Comment: You're sendind an ajax request for each symbol. Ajax is asynchronous so your second request can finish first than your previous one. 
The different number can be because a request was not satisfied yet or not satisfied at all. Use fiddler to check the http messages

Comment: Try to use JSON.stringify on client and javascriptserializer on server.

Comment: Replace all the fancy unicode with "a b c ... z" and try again. That is, reduce the problem to a *minimal* test-case - either show a sequence error *or* a unicode encoding error.

Answer (score 2):

The `$.ajax` call is asynchronous. There is no guarantee that one will finish before the other, in order, when firing multiple requests simultaneously.

So no, it's not a bug.

Comment: Even so, I should get the same set of characters in different orders. But the appearence of characters are different every time.

Comment: As other have suggested, use fiddler or some other tool to sniff the wire to see the actual requests and responses. Chanses are it has a natural explanaiton.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that my webservice is not fast enough to handle all ajax query. so it doesn't return result sometimes.